# Vue Native - Getting data from an api using axios are not shown on the page

Tags: react-native, vue.js, vue-native

I wanna create a basic app that just shows the data fetching from an api. I'm using Vue Native which is the mixture of React Native + Vuejs but after I get the data it doesn't show the data on the page.

My code is:

```
<template>
    <view class="container">
        <view v-if="this.cars.length">
            <h1>{{this.cars[1][0]['title']}}</h1>
            <view v-for="(car, index) in this.cars[1][1]" :key="index">
                <image :source="{uri: 'https://example.com'+car['images'][0]['path']}" />
            </view>
        </view>
        <view v-else>
            <text>No car!</text>
        </view>
    </view>
</template>

<style>
.container {
    background-color: white;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    flex: 1;
}
</style>

<script>
    import axios from 'axios';
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                cars: {},
            }
        },
        mounted() {
            axios.get('https://example.com/api/cars')
                .then(cars => {
                    this.cars = cars.data;
                })
        },
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

You should change cars: {} to cars: []

Then in your v-for="car in cars". Then you can get your data like for example car.Name

That's how it works for me, hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Try to save the instance and then run axios

```
mounted() {
            const vm = this
            axios.get('https://example.com/api/cars')
                .then(cars => {
                    vm.cars = cars.data;
                })
        },
```